# bootstrap switch does not work for dynamically created checkbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following combination of scripts :
**jquery**, **bootstrap**, **modernizer**, **json2html**.

calling something like :

```
<script>
   $('#my01Switch').bootstrapSwitch({
            onText: 'ON',
            offText: 'OFF',
            size: 'large',
            onColor: 'success',
            offColor: 'warning',
            labelText: '*'
        });
    </script>
```

just before the closing body tag,  on :

```
<input name="my01Switch" id="my01Switch" data-toggle="switch" checked="" type="checkbox">
```

The above is dynamically generated input tag.

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if document is ready before you execute the bootstrap switch plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Code
});
```

Update switch checkbox code:

Add a class to the checkbox

```
<input name=\"my01Switch\" id=\"my01Switch\" type=\"checkbox\"  data-toggle=\"switch\" checked=\"true\" class=\"custom-box\"/>
```

Update js code:

```
function renderRooms(json)
{
    if (json !== undefined) {

        //.....

        //$('#roomBoxWrap').json2html(json, transforms.theRoom);
        $('#form-nav').json2html(json.rooms, transforms.menurooms);
        $('#title_room_name').append(getRoomName(json));

        //After the rooms are loaded
        $('.custom-box').bootstrapSwitch();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah. Am calling within the doc ready as you have mentioned. still don't work.

Comment: Two : 1.> Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead

2.>Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

But these are in Jquery code 2.0.3...

Comment: and which jquery version do you use? Also how do you create your checkbox, can you show us your code?

Comment: can you add the kitchen code directly on to your html page in order to see if this is working?

Comment: it is already on the page. links are provided only to plug-in code ( js and css )

Pls right click and view source. Its down below if you scroll all the way down.

Comment: Adding class="custom-box" did not help.. :(

Comment: Can you upload this to the live website?

Comment: Please help me understand what you mean by "live website". The link I have given IS a Live one. It pulls JSON from a Live URL. Everything is Real Dev env.

Comment: //After the rooms are loaded
        $('.custom-box').bootstrapSwitch();

That worked ! Thanks. :)